# Trying to test weak scaling of a parallel program?

Tags: parallel-processing, scaling

I am trying to understand weak scaling in context of parallel programming. I have a parallel matrix multiplication implementation that I would like to test weak scaling.

The best resource I have found is here: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse260-a/HW/A4/

Here, it says we will scale using the function `N^3 /  P = N_0`. Where N is the input size, `P` is the number of processors, and `N_0` is the amount of data we use for 1 processor (the value we are holding constant. Using this formula, it says the schedule for running the the program will vary as follows when `N_0 = 3250`.

```
Cores   N
4       5160
16      8192
64      13004
```

I cannot figure out how they are deriving these numbers for `N`. I have tried so many calculations. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

See here for the [computational complexity of matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra). I think this is where they obtained the `N^3/P` formula. Which basically says that multiplying to `NxN` matrices will take `O(N^3)` time. Split across P processes each process will, in theory, take `N^3/P` time.

Now, on to how they obtained the numbers in the table. Notice how if you calculate `N^3/P` for each of the entries in the table you obtain a relative stable value for `N_0`:

```
P   N      N^3/P
4   5160   3.435x10^10
16  8192   3.436x10^10
64  13004  3.436x10^10
```

How did they get these numbers? Well, lets start with the fact that `N_0 = 3250` for 1 process. Meaning that `N^3/P = 3250^3/1 = 3.433x10^10`. Now that we have this starting value for amount of work each process needs to do, we can grow the numbers by adhering to this formula: `3250^3/1 = N^3/P`. We can set `P` to whatever we want, leaving only N to be solved for. You then make sure that N is rounded up to down to be evenly divisible by `P`.